# finding infimum of the ratio of largest to smallest distance of six points in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, elementary-set-theory, problem-solving, supremum-and-infimum

How can we find the infimum of the following set
$$\left\{\frac{\max_{i\neq j}d(A_i,A_j)}{\min_{i\neq j}d(A_i,A_j)}:A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_6 \in \mathbb R^2, A_i\neq A_j (\forall i\neq j)\right\}.$$

This comes from a meme, but I thought it might be interesting to know what this infimum will be. But I did not make much progress on it (except for finding the ratio for some special cases).

Comment: Also I'm not sure what tags to put as I'm not sure which branch of mathematics this is most relevant to. If anyone can help me with that it would be great.

Comment: Well, you can achieve a ratio of 2 by starting with 3 vertices of an equilateral triangle and then adding the three midpoints of the sides of that triangle.

Comment: You can get a ratio slightly smaller than 2 by using the same 3 starting vertices of an equilateral triangle, then finding 3 new points by starting with the midpoints of the sides and slightly moving them outside of the triangle in directions orthogonal to their sides.  If my geometry is correct, I believe this gives a ratio of $\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+(2-\sqrt{3})^2}}\approx 1.93185$.

Comment: Taking the five vertices and the center of a regular pentagon gives a ratio of $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} \approx 1.90211$.

Comment: I think it is not pertinent to talk about infimum when trying with a finite and fixed set of points. For each fixed set $\{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,A_5,A_6\}$ there is a determined mínimal number for $\dfrac{\max_{i\neq j}d(A_i,A_j)}{\min_{i\neq j}d(A_i,A_j)}$.

Comment: @Piquito This set is infinite because there is an infinite number of ways to choose six points in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @Ryan Hu But in this case is not clear that the max can be large and the min can be very small?

Comment: @Piquito Yes, that's why we are looking for an infimum. The set is clearly not bounded above!

Comment: @Ryan Hu: Ah, it is true. your quetion is not about the Sup but about the Inf.